# HTML error when using union types in component field

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to make a form generator component and I have design form field class like the below:

```
export type FormField<T, TDropDown = any> =
  | InputFormField<T>
  | DropdownFormField<TemplateStringsArray, TDropDown>;

export interface InputFormField<T> {
  key: Extract<keyof T, string>;
  type: 'string' | 'date' | 'number';
}

export interface DropdownFormField<T, TDropDown> {
  type: 'dropdown';
  key: Extract<keyof T, string>;
  dropdownItems: Observable<TDropDown[]>;
  dropdownItemTitleKey: keyof TDropDown;
  dropdownItemValueKey: keyof TDropDown;
}
```

So I have two types of the form field. If the type of form field is dropdown then dropdown items must be filled, otherwise, those fields are not necessary.

In the HTML file, I have used this type like below:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of formFields" nz-col nzXs="24" nzMd="12" nzLg="8">
  <nz-form-item>
    <nz-form-label>
       {{ item.key }}
    </nz-form-label>
    <nz-form-control>
      <ng-container [ngSwitch]="item.type">
        <nz-select
          *ngSwitchCase="'dropdown'"
          [formControlName]="item.key"
          nzShowSearch
        >
          <nz-option
            *ngFor="let option of item.dropdownItems | async"
            [nzLabel]="option[item.dropdownItemTitleKey]"
            [nzValue]="option[item.dropdownItemValueKey]"
          ></nz-option>
        </nz-select>
      </ng-container>
    </nz-form-control>
  </nz-form-item>
</div>
```

I have used *ngSwitchCase="'dropdown'" to make sure the item is a dropdown item, but I still get this error:

```
Property 'dropdownItems' does not exist on type 'SarmadInputFormField<T>'
```

What is the proper way to define a form field class and use It inside a component HTML file?

Comment: Your check does not directly imply that the item is of `DropdownFormField<T, TDropDown>` type. It only implies that the `type` field on `FormField<T, TDropDown = any>` is `dropdown`, and those are two different things. Look into [type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) - I'm not sure how type checks are handled in template parsing, but perhaps it will help.

Comment: thanks for your response. checking for type works fine in typescript but it seems that template type checkings are different from ts files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, Angular's template does not support downcasting types. This is why even you used `*ngSwitchCase` - Angular isn't able to determine the right sub-type of your union-type.

If it was in `.ts` file, you could use `as` keyword to downcasting it. But again, this option is not available in template's syntax.

Your solution would be, using the `$any()` keyword. This is supplied by angular exactly for such cases, to disable type checking when your type in template does not match the exact right type.

So your code should look like the following:

```
*ngFor="let option of $any(item.dropdownItems | async)"
```

More about `$any()` you can find [here](https://angular.io/guide/template-typecheck#troubleshooting-template-errors):

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about $any(), but there is no way to still use IDE intellisense? I am using pipes right now, but I was wondering what others do.

Comment: No. there is no way as much as I know.

Comment: The same problem occours with the Angular API itself, not only with custom types